# How to use custom Annotation Processors with Buck?

Tags: java, android, dagger, annotation-processing, buck

As the title states - I'd like use custom Java Annotation Processors with Buck (e.g. Dagger 1 / 2). Checking out the documentation did not reveal any evident annotation-processing related properties for any Java (or Android) related build rules, and I also couldn't find any examples for this scenario.

I did find [this issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/85) on GitHub though, without any meaningful recent answers.

Is this something that Buck still does not support?
In case not, did anyone find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coneko points you to the code in question in that issue.  Every build rule in Buck has a Description with an `Arg` class that describes the arguments the rule takes.  In the case of `java_library`, there is `annotation_processor_deps`, `annotation_pocessor_params`, `annotation_processors`, and `annotation_processor_only`.

- `annotation_processor_deps` - the set of dependencies needed to run the annotation processor
- `annotation_pocessor_params` - the list of arguments to pass to the annotation processors
- `annotation_processors` - the annotation processors
- `annotation_processor_only` - `True` if this library is only an annotation processor

Comment: Ah great, managed to make both Android Annotations and Dagger 2 working by using these, thanks! Note - it'd help much if you could update the docs with these sometime :)

Comment: They aren't documented because we aren't happy with the syntax.  We're likely to move to something more like what Bazel does with `java_plugin`.  We try not to change the syntax of things that are documented.